# When document is imported using Documentum API, the import is successful but the document id is not generated

Tags: json, import, documentum

When document is imported using Documentum API, the documents gets imported successfully but the "document_id" property contains empty value. But the same gets generated when the document is manually imported in Documentum.

Need help with the properties that needs to be passed when importing a document using Documentum API so that it generates the value of "document_id" property?

API: [POST]
{{~}}/repositories/{{doc-base}}/folders/{{folder_id}}/documents?content-count=1&all-primary=false&format=pdf

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

What metadata are you sending on the multipart message? "document_id" is not a Documentum attribute, so you'll have to inform it as this looks like a custom attribute.

If "manually" (webtop? D2?) that attribute gets a value, might be a TBO/D2 config filling it automatically.

Only similar attribute from Documentum is r_object_id, and that is automatically populated (and should be a 09xxxxx)